# Add Columns to left of RDD Table-Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add two columns to the left of my rdd. When I run the code below, the output is:

```
ID,Name,AGE
1,James,15
```

Code:
    #Import Key Functions
    import sys
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

```
#Create Spark context with Spark configuration
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Read Text to RDD - Python")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)


if __name__ == "__main__":


  # read input text files present in the directory to RDD
  lines = sc.textFile("/home/path/sample5.txt")
  # collect the RDD to a list
  llist = lines.collect()


  # print the list
  def rdd(x):
    for line in x:
        print(line)

def add_col(s):
    llist.insertColumn(creation_data,create_by,Modified_by)
    return 

rdd(llist)
```

I am trying to get the output to look like this:

```
Creation_Date, Create_By,Modified_By, ID,Name,Age
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pandaas? please find herewith a sample, hope this helps:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ["81A01", "81A02", "81A03"], 'name': ["NAME 01", "NAME 02", "NAME 03"],'age': ["31", "42", "23"]})
df1.insert(0, 'Creation_Date', "01-01-2019")
df1
Out[11]: 
  Creation_Date age     id     name
0    01-01-2019  31  81A01  NAME 01
1    01-01-2019  42  81A02  NAME 02
2    01-01-2019  23  81A03  NAME 03
```

Usage: df1.insert(loc=idx, column='A', value=new_col_data).  Feel free to explore.

To convert to RDD:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df1)
df.rdd.collect()
```